# Auto trigger new shipment email in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I have an inventory system called BrightPearl that manages all of my orders for magento (1.9.1) that is connected to shipstation. When an order is processed (i.e a labels is printed) ship station will send the data to brightpearl and brightpearl will then send the data to magento.

The order is marked complete and the tracking number is entered into the order.

The problem is that the shipment notification email is not being sent out.

Is there something that I can do that will auto send out all of those emails every hour (or every half day) or is there a setting that I need to select that will send those emails out automatically when a tracking number is added to the order and a shipment "invoice" is created?

Thanks!

Comment: Check my answer and accept if it works for you.

Comment: Have you found solution? This setting is already done in my system..

Answer (score 1):

Go to system> configuration > sales > sales emails
[image]
[image]

**If filling these settings doesn't work, contact Brightpearl**